# How read .hdf5 file with name like (1,1)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5, rhdf5

I have an hdf5 file that I would like to read the subgroup of it.

```
file is 'GSE77565_FBD_IC-heatmap-chr-10k.hdf5.gz' that downloaded from GEO number= 'GSE77565'
```

I read the data like below:

```
library(rhdf5)

h5f = H5Fopen("file.hdf5")
h5f 
HDF5 FILE 
        name /
    filename 

        name       otype dclass           dim
0  (0, 0)    H5I_DATASET FLOAT  24926 x 24926
1  (1, 1)    H5I_DATASET FLOAT  24320 x 24320
2  (10, 10)  H5I_DATASET FLOAT  13501 x 13501
```

but when I want to read one of the name I faced wth error:

```
h5f$"(1, 1)"
Error: Unable to read dataset.
Not all required filters available.
Missing filters: lzf
```

Also, I could not open any subgroup:

```
h5f_1 = H5Fopen("file.hdf5","(1, 1)")
Error: Unable to read dataset.
Not all required filters available.
 Missing filters: lzf
In addition: Warning message:
In h5checktypeOrOpenLoc(file, readonly = TRUE, native = native) :
  An open HDF5 file handle exists. If the file has changed on disk meanwhile, the function may not work properly. Run 'h5closeAll()' to close all open HDF5 object handles.

h5f&"(1, 1)"
HDF5 DATASET 
    name /(1, 1)
filename 
    type H5T_IEEE_F64LE
    rank 2
    size 24320 x 24320
 maxsize 24320 x 24320
```

Comment: Are you using bioconductor?

Comment: yes and use library(rhdf5).

Comment: It would be helpful to put the library statement in your code so that people would not have to track that down.